# Entangled Photon (laser pointer)

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement, laser, pair-production

From a laser pointer emission;

1. is it creating entangled pairs of photon?
2. is it possible to get more than "pair" entangled, like group of photons all entangled?

Comment: When you say "entangled", do you mean that the state space for the pair is a tensor product space, or do you mean that the state space for the pair is a tensor product space *and* the state of the pair is not expressible as a tensor product?  If the former, then the answer to 1 is certainly yes.  As for 2---sure, by either definition.

Comment: Thx for your quick reply. I have to read about "tensor", I'm really not that technical. Just starting at 34yo science general concepts interests.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, a laser pointer doesn't create entangled photon pair, there is no process involved that would cause it.
2. Until now I haven't heard of entangled more-than-two particles. However now that you've asked I stumbled over a [recent publication](http://www.livescience.com/47844-tangled-photon-triplets-quantum-telecommunication.html) mentioning entangled photon triplets.

Comment: Of course you can entangle more than two particles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_entanglement